# jquery when id is scrolltop change css

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrolltop

I need that when a 'id' spend in Top, the button changes the css

then get something like this:

*css

```
.active{
background:red;
}

.inactive{
background:#FFF;
}
```

*buttons:

```
<div id="button1" class="inactive">Box 1</div>
<div id="button2" class="inactive">Box 2</div>
```

*id's:

```
<span id="start1"></span>
Content Box 1
bla bla bla
<span id="end1"></span>

<span id="start2"></span>
Content Box 2
bla bla bla
<span id="end2"></span>
```

*script

```
when '#start1' is scrolltop,
('#button1').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
('#button2').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');

when '#end1' is scrolltop, **in case of passing the top with the scroll upwards
('#button1').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
('#button2').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive'); 

when '#start2' is scrolltop,
('#button2').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
('#button1').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');

when '#end2' is scrolltop, **in case of passing the top with the scroll upwards
('#button2').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
('#button1').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
```

Please, suggest.

Comment: When you say "when '#start1' is scrolltop,", do you mean "when `#start1` has been scrolled all the way to the top"?

Comment: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: Blazemonger, exactly, that's right. I'm sorry if I spoke wrongly.